# Azure Table Storage Vs On-premises NoSql

Tags: azure, nosql, large-data

I need to consider a database to store large volumes of data. Though my initial requirement is to simply retrieve chunks of data and save them in excel file, I am expecting more complex use cases for this data in future where the data will be consumed by different applications especially for analytics - hence need to use aggregated queries.

I am open to use either cloud based storage or on-premises storage. I am considering azure storage table (when there is a need to use aggregated data, I can have a wrapper service + cache around azure table storage but eventually will end up with nosql type storage) and on-premises MongoDB. Can someone suggest pros and cons of saving large data in azure table storage Vs on-premises MongoDB/couchbase/ravendb? Cost factor can be ignored.

Comment: I'd start with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989465/azure-table-vs-mongodb-on-azure) about Table Storage vs MongoDB.

Comment: I have come across many posts that actually compares cloud based MongoDb rather than on-premise MongoDb. Hence used "Azure Table Storage Vs On-premises NoSql" title

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question may end up getting closed due to its broad nature and potential for gathering more opinions than fact. That said:

This is really going to be an app-specific architecture issue, dealing with latency and bandwidth, as well as the need to maintain on-premises servers and other resources. On-prem, you'll have full control of your hardware resources, but if you're doing high-volume querying against your database, from the cloud, your performance will be hampered by latency and bandwidth. Cloud-based storage (whether in MongoDB or any other database) will have the advantage of being neighbors with your app if set up in the same data center.

Keep in mind: Any persistent database store will need to back its data in Azure Storage, meaning a mounted disk backed by Blob storage. You'll need to deal with the 1TB-per-disk size limit (expanding to 16TB on an 8-core box via stripe), and you'll need to compare this to your storage needs. If you need to go beyond 16TB, you'll need to either shard, go with 200TB Table storage, or go with on-prem MongoDB. But... MongoDB and Table Storage are two different beasts, one being document-based with a focus on query strength, the other a key/value store with very high speed discrete lookups. Comparing the two on the notion of on-prem vs cloud is secondary (in my opinion) to comparing functionality as it relates to your app.